# Different approaches to $g\left(\nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}X,e_i\right)+g\left(\nabla_{e_i}X,\nabla_{e_j}e_i\right)=0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

> Let $S$ be a $(1,1)$-tensor. Let $(e_i)$ be a local frame and let $(e^i)$ be its dual. Prove that
> $$X\left(S\left(e_i,e^i\right)\right)=(\nabla_XS)\left(e_i,e^i\right).\tag{1}$$

This formula exactly means that $\nabla_X$ commutes with the contraction. We can prove this via normal coordinates:

Let $(x^i)$ be normal coordinates centered at $p$. Then
\begin{align}
\left(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}}S\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},dx^i\right)(p)
&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\Big|_p\left(S\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},dx^i\right)\right)
-S\left(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big|_p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},dx^i\right)
-S\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\big|_p}dx^i\right)\\
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\left(S\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},dx^i\right)\right)(p)
\end{align}
Since formula (1) is cleary coordinate-independent, the conclusion easily follows.

**Now I want to learn more approaches other than the above one.**
In other words, I am wondering other natural methods to show
$$S\left(\nabla_Xe_i,e^i\right)+S\left(e_i,\nabla_Xe^i\right)=0,\tag{2}$$
where (2) is clearly equivalent to (1).
Any helps would be highly appreciated!

**Added**

Maybe the original problem seems trivial. Then I want to ask another problem:

> Let $(e_i)$ be a local orthonormal frame. Prove that
> $$g\left(\nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}X,e_i\right)+g\left(\nabla_{e_i}X,\nabla_{e_j}e_i\right)=0$$
> for any vector field $X$.

This is clearly a corollary of the original problem. Now I am wondering **other approaches**. Thanks for in advance for any hints!

Comment: You could do it without normal coordinates and put all the Christoffel symbols in. It's not much longer.

Comment: You can also rewrite the calculation containing the Christoffel symbols into one that uses only the abstract notation. But it's an even longer calculation. Your proof is probably the easiest one. If you want to avoid the full generality of normal coordinates, it's easy to use simple algebra to construct coordinates where the Christoffel symbols vanish at a point.

Comment: @Deane Thanks for your response! I understand what you said, and it seems that we'd better use normal coordinates whenever it brings us convenience. However, over reliance on normal coordinates makes my intuition of calculation much weaker. For example, when I did a complicated calculation, I met the term $S\left(\nabla_Xe_i,e^i\right)+S\left(e_i,\nabla_Xe^i\right)$ for $S=\nabla X$ and I didn't realize that it's zero. It bothers me a lot.

Comment: I think there is a general principle that the covariant derivative obeys the product rule when contracting two tensors. So, for example, $$ \partial_X(S_{ij}T^{ij}) = \nabla_XS_{ij}T^{ij} + S_{ij}\nabla_XT^{ij}$$ Notice that this should hold for any connection on a vector bundle and no metric is needed. But you can still use the normal coordinates trick by using a gauge transformation instead. Now that I think of it, I think this is the trick that Uhlenbeck showed Hamilton.

Comment: I think the discussion here might be somewhat circuitous: first, you need to address how $\nabla S$ is even defined. In the coordinate-free setting, we usually define $\nabla$ on vector fields an add requirements (axioms) for how $\nabla$ interacts with tensor products/contractions so that the covariant derivative of an arbitrary tensor field is uniquely defined. The equality $\nabla_X(\operatorname{tr}(S))=\operatorname{tr}(\nabla_XS)$ is often one of these axioms.

Comment: @Kajelad Thanks for your response, but I don't think that we are treating things in a circuitous way. For instantce, a natural corollary is $g\left(\nabla_{\nabla_{e_j}e_i}X,e_i\right)+g\left( \nabla_{e_i}X,\nabla_{e_j}e_i \right)=0$ for any local orthonormal frame $(e_i)$, and it seems nontrivial at least for me.

Comment: @Chiquita Perhaps "circuitous" was the wrong word. I was merely pointing out that you may need to state the precise definition of $\nabla$ you're using.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a generalization using the language of bundles, maybe it is helpfull now or in the future (or never :P), atleast it is a different approach.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. In general if $E,F$ are bundles with connection over $M$ one can define a connection on the bundle $\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$ by requiring the product rule $\nabla (Ae)=(\nabla A)e+A(\nabla e)$ for all $A\in\Gamma\mathrm{Hom}(E,F)$, $e\in\Gamma E$. The trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb R$ has a natural connection $d$.

Therefore given $E$  with connection one has connections on $E^*$, $\mathrm {End}E$, $(\mathrm {End}E)^*$ and so on. Then  the trace $\mathrm{tr}$ is a section of $(\mathrm {End}E)^*$  The claim now is that $\nabla \mathrm{tr}=0$ or equivalently $(\nabla \mathrm{tr})S=0$ for all $S\in\Gamma\mathrm {End}E$. It suffices to show this for $S$ of the form $S=e^*\otimes e$ with $e\in\Gamma E$,  $e^*\in\Gamma E^*$. Notice $\mathrm{tr}(e^*\otimes e)=e^*(e)$, so

$$
d(\mathrm{tr}S)
=d(e^*(e))
=(\nabla e^*)(e)+e^*(\nabla e)\\
=\mathrm{tr}((\nabla e^*)\otimes e+e^*\otimes\nabla e)
=\mathrm{tr}(\nabla(e^*\otimes e))
=\mathrm{tr}(\nabla S)
$$

Here also the product rule for the tensor product was used. Hence $(\nabla\mathrm{tr})S=d(\mathrm{tr}S)-\mathrm{tr}(\nabla S)=0$ and so $\nabla\mathrm{tr}=0$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another answer to your original question:

First, let's recall that given a connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E$, there are uniquely defined connections on $E$ and $E^*\otimes E$, where for any sections $v$ of $E$ and $\theta$ of $E^*$,
\begin{align*}
  \partial_X\langle\theta,v\rangle &= \langle\nabla_X\theta,v\rangle + \langle \theta,\nabla_Xv\rangle\\
  \nabla_X(\theta\otimes v) &= (\nabla_X\theta)\otimes v + \theta\otimes\nabla_Xv.
\end{align*}

Let $(e_1, \dots, e_m)$ be a frame of $E$ with dual frame $(e^1, \dots, e^m)$. We want to show that given any section $S$ of $E^*\otimes E$,
$$
  S(\nabla_{X}e_i, e^i) + S(e_i,\nabla_X e^i) = 0.
$$
It suffices to prove it for $S = \theta\otimes v$. This follows by the following straightforward calculation:
\begin{align*}
  (\theta\otimes v)(\nabla_{X}e_i, e^i) + (\theta\otimes v)(e_i,\nabla_X e^i)
  &= \langle\theta,\nabla_Xe_i\rangle\langle e^i,v\rangle
    +
    \langle \theta,e_i\rangle\langle \nabla_Xe^i,v\rangle\\
  &= (\partial_X\langle\theta,e_i\rangle
    - \langle\nabla_X\theta, e_i\rangle)\langle e^i,v\rangle\\
&\quad
    + \langle\theta,e_i\rangle(\partial_X\langle e^i,v\rangle - \langle e^i,\nabla_Xv\rangle)\\
  &= \partial_X(\langle\theta,e_i\rangle\langle e^i,v\rangle)
    - \langle \nabla_X\theta, e_i\rangle\langle e^i,v\rangle
    - \langle \theta,e_i\rangle\langle e^i,\nabla_Xv\rangle\\
  &= \partial_X\langle\theta,v\rangle - \langle\nabla_X\theta,v\rangle - \langle\theta,\nabla_Xv\rangle\\
  &= 0
\end{align*}

Comment: Additional comment: To define the trace of a $(1,1)$ tensor invariantly, it suffices to do it for rank $1$-tensors $\theta\otimes v$, but the definition for that case is obvious.